# Make a book list at the end of a document based on books mentioned in footnotes

Tags: footnotes

Is this possible to automatize? I would like everything that is in the footnotes (author(s), title, year of publication/edition) except page numbers or chapter specifications. If it could be made to work, do I have to write the footnotes in some uniform way?

Comment: Do you use bibtex/biblatex for the footnote (via footcite)? if yes, afair there are way to generate more than one bibliography at the end of the document, based on a custom field for book/nobook.

Comment: I don't know; the thing I know I have is `\usepackage{scrextend}`, `\deffootnote[1.8em]{0pt}{1.6em}{\makebox[1.8em][l]{\thefootnotemark.}}`, and then I use it like this `\footnote{Padron-McCarthy and Risch: {\em Databasteknik} (2005), chapters 5 and 11.}`.

Comment: So no bibTeX/bibLaTeX but manual references. You should consider to switch to bibLaTeX, makes things a lot easier if you have many literature references. Are you familiar with bibLaTeX?

Comment: Aha, no, never heard of it.

Comment: Okay, thought so. Check http://uweziegenhagen.de/?p=2501 for a simple document I just uploaded. It uses biblatex and biber. It's the best way once you made the little learning curve. To separate the bibliography (just one for books) check out http://texblog.org/2012/10/22/multiple-bibliographies-with-biblatex/

Comment: It works well with two bilbiographies at the end, one for everything, one for just the books. I updated the blog entry and go back to sleep now.

Comment: I read your question again, I guess you originally wanted only a simple bibliography. In this case you can ignore the stuff with the second bibliography. If my comments helped you, I'll formulate an answer you may accept.

Comment: @UweZiegenhagen: Sure, go ahead.

Comment: Done! Happy TeXing!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is simply a *bibliography*, which is one of LaTeX's specialties. Nowadays a combination of `biblatex`and `biber` should be *the* combination to cover all requirements. Here is a simple example showing the basic steps:

1. Create the bib file: Create a file `myliterature.bib` in a
   directory and put in:

   ```
   @Article{weinhold,
   author = {F. Weinhold and C.R. Landis},
   title = {Natural Bond Orbitals and Extensions of Localized Bonding Concept},
   year ={2001},
   journal = {Chemistry in Europe: Research and Practice in Europe},
   volume = {2},
   number = {2},
   pages = {91-104}}
   ```

   There are dedicated tools to manage these bib-files, e.g. [JabRef](http://jabref.sourceforge.net/) or Citavi, have a look at them in case you have a lot of  references.
2. Create the TeX file:

   Create a file `test.tex` in the same directory as the bib-file with
   the following content:

   ```
   \documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
   \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
   \usepackage[english]{babel}

   \usepackage[style=authortitle-icomp,backend=biber]{biblatex}%

   \addbibresource{myliterature.bib}

   \begin{document}

   \cite{weinhold}

   \clearpage

   \parencite{weinhold}

   \clearpage

   \footcite[12]{weinhold}

   \clearpage

   \smartcite[12, smart]{weinhold}

   \clearpage

   \citeauthor{weinhold}

   \clearpage

   \citetitle{weinhold}

   \clearpage

   \citeyear{weinhold}

   \nocite{*}

   \printbibliography 

   \end{document}
   ```
3. Compile the files

   ```
   pdflatex test
   biber test
   pdflatex test
   ```

   and enjoy the final bibliography. There are lots of resources, I
   recommend you the `biblatex` manual and a Google search on
   `biblatex`to get more insights, how it works and how you can
   influence the design of the references.